# Sample Ruby code, How is this abstracting things out?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Watching this video by Yehuda, and he gave this snippet about how Ruby helps you build better abstractions.

```
class FOWA
    def self.is_fun
        def fun?
            true
        end
    end


    is_fun
end
```

He was talking about, in ruby, how if you are repeating code in your class over and over again, you can abstract it out without having to think about things in terms of methods etc.  And he said this was using a metaprogramming technique.

Can someone explain what this is?

It is a class method on FOWA (so its like a static method, you don't need an instance to call it), and this class method is really just wrapping another method that returns true.

And this is_fun class method is now being executed or what? not sure what the last line "is_fun" is doing?

http://vimeo.com/11679138

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `is_fun` call at the end of the class calls the static method. The static method then defines the `fun?` method inside of the FOWA class.  Then, you can do this:

```
f = FOWA.new
f.fun?
```

If you take out the `is_fun` call at the end of the class, the `fun?` method doesn't get defined.

He mentioned that you wouldn't use it in this way, but the point is how easy it is to dynamically add a method to a class. You might use it like this if you wanted the method to be available in subclasses and you wouldn't call `is_fun` in FOWA, but you might in a subclass. It gets a little more interesting if you have a parameter for `is_fun` and the definition of `fun?` changes depending on that parameter.

This also leads right into `modules` because you can define a `module` with the same `is_fun` method and then just have your class `extend` the `module` and the methods in the `module` are available in the class. You would use this technique if you want your method to be available to more than just subclasses of FOWA.

Comment: ok I get it, but if the caller or user of the instance f were to call f.is_fun it would then create the method on the fly I would presume, instead of the class defenition doing this.. dangerous stuff!